# Is code first migration automatically run on the server?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am very familiar with Entity Framework using Database First approach and how to deploy the solution with it.

Basically, in my solution with database first approach, I have a web client project that consumes data access library project that is coded with database first approach.

So, first, I write some SQL Server scripts to add new tables (or make schema changes).

Next, go to the data access library project, using EF edmx designer to update .net from existing database, compile this data access layer, and the DDL reference is automatically updated in the client web project.

When I deploy the solution to the production server:

1. First, I need to run the t-SQL scripts on the production SQL server
2. Next, I deploy the 2 updated DDLs (one for the web and 1 for the data access layer) on the web server.

Now, I have a new application that includes a web project and a data access layer project that uses EF Code First approach.
I am new to EF code first approach. I know any time when I change the database schema, for instance adding a new table, I need to run code first migration in the Package Management Console in Visual Studio to let my back-end database instance change/update.

**My question:**

When I deploy the application to the production, what are the steps I should follow?

How is the production SQL server updated that is created with EF Code First approach?

Is it a automatic process or I have to run the migration manually like I do inside Visual Studio under the Package Management Console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Azure then you can configure it has automatic process as shown below.

[image]

Else you have to do it manually like this :

You have to create a db script and after that you can run it on your production db.

**PM> Update-Database -Script**

You can refer this doc : [**Getting a SQL Script**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)

**Another option where I normaley use :**

When I need to run migrations aginst the production db,I change my `conn` string to reflect production db and after that run :

**PM> Update-Database**

Comment: Didn't know about the Azure option; that's cool. There are other automatic ways though.

Comment: yep,you can do it easily if you're using Azure : ) @BradleyDotNET

Comment: Hi Sampath. Thank you so much for your answer.  It seems, when I deploy the app to the production server I have to run the migration code inside my VS with database connection string changed to production.

Comment: are you using Azure or which host ?

Comment: I have put another option too.please see that too :)

Answer (score 4):

You have several options with migrations.

1. You can generate a script using Update-Database -Script (as @Sampath notes)
2. You can run Update-Database -ConnectionString="YourDbString" and it will do it against the production database for you
3. You can use a migration *initializer* and on app startup it will use the applications connection string to run the migration. Do this by putting a line similar to this in your initialization routine:

   ```
   Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
   ```

Where `Context` is your DbContext type and `Configuration` is the configuration class generated when you made the first migration.

See this MSDN article for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Comment: the problem on your 3rd option is,do we need to change the `conn` each and every time ? I mean `dev` to `prod` ?

Comment: @Sampath yes and no, you should be changing the connection string *already* so the production app talks to the production DB and by doing so the initializer will work.

Comment: Fourth => You can provide a dacpac :D DBA like that solution

Comment: @CodeNotFound I'm not sure, but I think I'm glad I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET All 3 options you gave are not maintenable when multiple developpers generate the script => many conflicts that are difficult to fix. Dacpac by the way is more maintenable and conflicts are fixed more easy

Comment: Dacpac is a tool from SSDT => https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXZFCZh6Hbg

Comment: @CodeNotFound I can definitely see multiple devs creating migrations at the same time being a problem; but once you are "ready for release" I'm not sure the issue is as bad as you describe. Still, thanks for the knowledge :)